# Compare two objects (the order is not important, only the keys and values)

Tags: javascript

Let's write a function compareRobots, that takes 2 robots and returns true, if only all the characteristics of both are the same. (the order is not important, only the keys and values).

Notes:
each robot has its own unique serialNo (do not check it when comparing)
properties can't have values of undefined and NaN.

```
  const charlie = { serialNo: 1, chipVer: 12 };
  const lordy = { serialNo: 2, chipVer: 12 };
  compareRobots(charlie, lordy); // true

  const paul = { serialNo: 3, chipVer: 15 };
  compareRobots(paul, charlie); // false

   const mike = { serialNo: 4, chipVer: 12, wheels: 1 };
   compareRobots(mike, charlie); // false

   const max = { serialNo: 5, engineVer: 12 };
   compareRobots(max, charlie); // false

   const steve = { serialNo: 6 };
   compareRobots(steve, charlie); // false`
```

I write a code but I don't know how to ignore the serialNo of robots

```
const compareRobots = (robot1, robot2) => {
// write code here
const entries1 = Object.entries(robot1);
const entries2 = Object.entries(robot2);

if (entries1.length !== entries2.length) {
  return false;
};

for (let i = 0; i < entries1.length; i++) {
  if (entries1[i][0] !== entries2[i][0]) {
    return false;
  }

  if (entries1[i][1] !== entries2[i][1]) {
    return false;
  }
};

  return true;
};`
```

Comment: use Object.keys() to loop over the first array, and compare with the second

Comment: Have you looked into [lodash `isEqualWith`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#isEqualWith)? It might help here. There's also [`isMatchWith`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#isMatchWith), which you might want to look at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) and a [Set()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) to get all unique keys of the two objects, then I simply remove the ones I don't want to compare (`"serialNo"`)

```js
function compareRobots(a, b) {
  // determine all unique keys
  const keys = new Set([].concat(Object.keys(a), Object.keys(b)));
  // ignore serialNo;
  keys.delete("serialNo");

  for (const k of keys)
    if (a[k] !== b[k]) return false;
  return true;
}

const charlie = { serialNo: 1, chipVer: 12 };
const lordy = { serialNo: 2, chipVer: 12 };
const paul = { serialNo: 3, chipVer: 15 };
const mike = { serialNo: 4, chipVer: 12, wheels: 1 };
const max = { serialNo: 5, engineVer: 12 };
const steve = { serialNo: 6 };

console.log({
  "charlie, lordy": compareRobots(charlie, lordy), // true
  "paul, charlie": compareRobots(paul, charlie), // false
  "mike, charlie": compareRobots(mike, charlie), // false
  "max, charlie": compareRobots(max, charlie), // false
  "steve, charlie": compareRobots(steve, charlie), // false`
});
```

Comment: This not handle NaN values

Comment: @MarcoRiccetti yes, and it doesn't distinguish between `0` and `-0`, and neither does it distinguish between `!(key in obj)` and `ob[key] = undefined`. granted. But these are minor implementation details and can easily be fixed by OP if required or even wanted.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Array#every` over the entries of one object, with a special case that doesn't compare values for the `'serialNo'` key.

```js
const compareRobots = (r1, r2) => {
  const entries1 = Object.entries(r1);
  if (entries1.length !== Object.keys(r2).length) return false;
  return entries1.every(([k, v]) => k === 'serialNo' || k in r2 && v === r2[k]);
};
const charlie = { serialNo: 1, chipVer: 12 };
const lordy = { serialNo: 2, chipVer: 12 };
console.log(compareRobots(charlie, lordy)); // true
const paul = { serialNo: 3, chipVer: 15 };
console.log(compareRobots(paul, charlie)); // false
const mike = { serialNo: 4, chipVer: 12, wheels: 1 };
console.log(compareRobots(mike, charlie)); // false
const max = { serialNo: 5, engineVer: 12 };
console.log(compareRobots(max, charlie)); // false
const steve = { serialNo: 6 };
console.log(compareRobots(steve, charlie)); // false`
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like that will do the trick:

```
const compare = (first, second) => {
  let isEqual = true;
  Object.keys(first).forEach((objKey) => {
     if (objKey !== 'serialNo' && first[objKey] === second[objKey]) {
       isEqual = false;
     }
  };
  return isEqual;
}
```

Comment: How to ignore different serial numbers?

Comment: i updated the answer, but you can figure out yourself next time

Comment: I did figure it out. But `isEqual` still reflects the equality of the last property checked, not all of them except serial number. Also if the last property checked is `serialNo`, `isEqual` is always false.

Comment: i edited, mybad

Comment: I suggest testing the code as well - there's another change to make.  You can ignore the last test case in @unmitigated 's answer if you like because the assignment allows you to assume properties are not `undefined` or `NaN`.

Answer (score 0):

You can write something like this:

```
// test objects
const charlie = { serialNo: 1, chipVer: 12, x: NaN, y: undefined  };
const lordy = { serialNo: 2, chipVer: 12, x: NaN, y: undefined };
const lordy2 = { serialNo: 3, chipVer: 13, x: NaN, y: undefined };
        
// compare function
function compareRobots(r1, r2) {
 // check equals
 if (r1 === r2)
  return true;
 // get objects keys
 const r1keys = Object.keys(r1);
 const r2keys = Object.keys(r2);
 // check not same keys size
 if (r1keys.length != r2keys.length)
  return false;
 // scan keys and check equality
 for(const key of r1keys) {
  // check equality (skip serialNo)
  if (
      key !== 'serialNo' && 
      (
       !r1.hasOwnProperty(key) ||
       (
        r1[key] !== r2[key] &&
        !isNaN(r1[key]) &&
        !isNaN(r2[key])
       )
      )
     ) return false;
  }
  // confirm equality
  return true;
}
        
// log results
console.log(compareRobots(charlie, lordy));
console.log(compareRobots(charlie, lordy2));
```